# Can't find my source code after exception thrown

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have been working on a single thread *C++* program using visual studio. I have been running the *"debug"* version and normally If I come across some kind of crash the debugger helpfully points me to the bad line in my code. Sometimes the crash happens within a *C++ library* function in which case I look over to the *"Call Stack"* window and can quickly spot the last call from my code which called the library function.

But now I am struggling with a *"Exception thrown"* problem where the crash occurs in `"strcat.asm"`, but the *Call Stack* does not display any code I recognise. In the call stack window I can see things like `"ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadstart@8()` - whatever that means!

How can I find what part of my code led to this crash?

**UPDATE:** after much pain, I finally found that the bug was essentially

```
value[idx] = a;
```

where `idx` had taken on the value -1. This, no doubt, had corrupted the stack.

Comment: I am not using multiple threads myself. But I guess it is possible that the compiler is creating code the does some things on other threads. Maybe this is what's happening - but I still don't know how to get the debugger to show me my code in my thread.

Comment: @Mick Take a look at [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0ab9610d-2535-4f2e-941d-8e8fd57db3e5/unhandled-exception-in-strcatasm).

Comment: That looks interesting and may be a good clue - but my program is pretty big and does an awful lot of string manipulation in many places, so I'm still keen to get the answer to my central question.

Comment: If the call stack doesn't make sense at all you may have smashed the stack completely, e.g. by writing outside a local array, or by passing around pointers and references to local variables.

Comment: That sounds plausible - though I would have hoped that the debugger would have helped me find that kind of cock-up!

Comment: Well, it does, a smashed stack is very easy to recognize.  Congratulations, you now know what it looks like.  It will happen again some rainy day if you don't start using strcat_s().

Comment: @Mick Unfortunately, the stack is where the debugger looks to see what's happening. Sometimes, especially if you're working with a lot of strings, you can figure out something about what's happened by recognising text that has accidentally overwritten the stack. (Spotting plausible text in hex data is a reasonably valuable debugging skill.)